# How to convert type of a variable when using JuMP

Tags: type-conversion, julia, julia-jump

I am using Julia/JuMP to implement an algorithm. In one part, I define a model with continues variables and solve the linear model. I do some other calculations based on which I add a couple constraints to the model, and then I want to solve the same problem but with integer variables. I could not use `convert()` function as it does not take variables.

I tried to define the variable again as integer, but the model did not seem to consider it! I provide a sample code here:

```
m = Model()
@defVar(m, 0 <= x <= 5)
@setObjective(m, Max, x)
@addConstraint(m, con, x <= 3.1)
solve(m) 
println(getValue(x))
@defVar(m, 0 <= x <= 1, Bin)
solve(m) 
println(getValue(x))
```

Would you please help me do this conversion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the second `@variable(m, 0 <= x <= 1, Bin)` actually creates a new variable in the model, but with the same name in Julia.

To change a variable from a continuous to a binary, you can do

```
setcategory(x, :Bin)
```

to change the variable bounds and class before calling solve again.

Comment: Thanks Iain, my other question is how to change the solver? for the original LP, I use `m=Model(solver=GurobiSolver(PreCrush=1, Cuts=0, Presolve=0, Heuristics=0.0))` so I can add my cuts. For the second problem, which is an IP, I want the solver to only use B&B and no cuts.

Comment: When I change the type of x, I get an error message `type JuMPArray has no field col`. However, it runs fine on another small sample code!

Comment: My bad! I should have put it in a for loop: `for j in 1:3 m.colcat[x[j].col] = :Int end`.

Comment: Any idea how to do this in newer JuMP versions (e.g. v0.21) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of JuMP, you need to use a different function than `setcategory`. The methods you are looking for are:

- `set_binary` Add binary constraint to variable.
- `unset_binary` Remove binary constraint from variable.
- `set_integer` Add integer constraint to variable.
- `unset_integer` Remove integer constraint from variable.

The documentation on this can be found [here](https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/stable/variables/#Integrality-utilities).