# How to change the type of a variable using JuMP?

Tags: julia-jump

I am using Julia/JuMP to write an algorithm. I have previously defined an MILP, but now I want to relax some of the integer restrictions. How can I do this?

Here is my sample code:

```
using JuMP
using Gurobi

model = Model(Gurobi.Optimizer)
@variable(model, 0 <= x[i=1:2], Int)
@constraint(model, x[1] + x[2] >= 0.5)
@objective(model, Min, 3*x[1] + x[2])

# *Here I want to relax the integer restriction on x[2]*

optimize!(model)
println(value.(x))
```

I have found an old post with the same question ([How to convert type of a variable when using JuMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27762510/how-to-convert-type-of-a-variable-when-using-jump)), but the solution (using the function `setcategory()`) does not seem to work in the current version of JuMP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `unset_integer`:
https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/stable/variables/#Integer-constraints-1

There is also `relax_integrality`
https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/stable/variables/#JuMP.relax_integrality

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for indeed.